# Comparing two multidimensional arrays in PHP to sum rates

Tags: php, arrays

I've two arrays:

**Array A:**

```
$rates = array(
    'apple' => array(
        'red' => array(
            'rate' => 1.19,
            'resume' => 'This is a red apple.'
        ),
        'green' => array(
            'rate' => 0.99,
            'resume' => 'This is a green apple.'
        ),
        'yellow' => array(
            'rate' => 0.89,
            'resume' => 'This is a yellow apple.'
        ),
    )
);
```

**Array B:**

```
$cart = array(
    'apple' => array(
        '0'  => red,
        '1'  => green
    )
);
```

---

The array B is the cart one and I need to get rates from Array A.

So:

- Apple > red > `1.19`
- Apple > green > `0.99`

Total should be `2.18`.

---

This is what I tried:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($cart as $key => $arr) {
    if (isset($rates[$key])) {
        foreach ($arr as $value) {
            $total += $rates[$key]['rate'][$value] ?? 0;
        }
    }
}
echo $total;
```

But it doesn't work.
https://3v4l.org/vsEvA

What I'm missing please ?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just nest the rates array with the info you have in the cart array and sum it.

```
$sum =0;
foreach($cart as $prod => $sub){
    foreach($sub as $color){
        $sum += $rates[$prod][$color]['rate'];
    }
}

echo $sum;
```

https://3v4l.org/C6U3f

Edit: I believe you only have the value and rate wrong way around in your code.
https://3v4l.org/pj3WL

Answer (score 0):

To point out the flaw in your original logic, you are not going to the level of the color of the `$rates` array.

Here is the logic with the missing part.

```
foreach ($cart as $key => $arr) {
    if (isset($rates[$key])) {
        foreach ($arr as $value) {
           foreach($rates[$key] as $colorKey => $color)
              if ($colorKey === $value)
                $total += $color['rate'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to loop rates array. It's associative and predicable. All the data you need is right there in the cart.

Comment: Yes. I see you are answering with that. I just wanted to point out the flaw in the original iteration - so OP can understand how to iterate completely. Thanks.